# I am just trying to run a batch file on server present in c drive in batch folder which is shared

Tags: java, batch-file, sas

I am just trying to run a batch file on server present in c drive in batch folder which is shared but I am getting an error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sas.bat" (in directory "\\xx.xx.xx.xx\batch"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

java code:

```
ProcessBuilder launcher = new ProcessBuilder();
launcher.redirectErrorStream(true);

launcher.directory(new File("\\\\xx.xx.xx.xx\\batch").getAbsoluteFile());
launcher.command("sas.bat");
Process p= launcher.start();
```

sas.bat:

```
"D:\sas home\SASFoundation\9.3\sas.exe" -SYSIN c:\codeexcel.sas
cmd /k
```

Comment: Why you need to use UNC path when the command (sas.bat) uses local path anyway, so it has to be executed locally?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt, you can use a UNC-Path like `\\server\folder`as a working directory directly.

Try using the whole path (e.g. `\\server\folder\test.bat`) as your command, maybe that works.

If not, you'll have to create a network drive with a specific drive letter first and use that drive letter for your command.

Comment: here  batch is my folder name:  launcher.directory(new File("\\xx.xx.xx.xx\\batch").getAbsoluteFile());

Comment: Based on what I've tried you have to use: launcher.command("\\\\xx.xx.xx.xx\\batch\\sas.cmd");

Answer (score 0):

Since it's Windows, you need to include the drive in the full path:

```
launcher.directory(new File("<your drive goes here>:\\xx.xx.xx.xx\\batch").getAbsoluteFile());
```

The double slash (`\\\\` in Java) does not make sense here.

Comment: I have put the drive but yet it does't work.launcher.directory(new File("/C \\xx.xx.xx.xx\\batch"));

Comment: Why `/C`? Use `C:\\xx.xx.xx.xx\\batch`

Comment: Does't work getting    java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sas.bat" (in directory "C:\xx.xx.xx.xx\batch"): CreateProcess error=267, The directory name is invalid

Comment: Hi   Adam Michalik can you please help me in this??

Answer (score 0):

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c",
    "F:\\Softwares\\PsTool\\PsExec.exe \\\\xx.xx.xx.xx -u Administrator -p yyyy \"c:\\batch\\createFolder.bat\"");
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process p = builder.start();
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String line;
while (true) {
    line = r.readLine();
    if (line == null) {
        break;
    }
    System.out.println(line);
}
```